# Applying Pompeiu formula for large disc R

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $g(z)$ be  a continuously differentiable function on the complex plane that is zero outside of som compact set. Show that $$g(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\iint_\mathbb{C}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{1}{z-w}dx\,dy,\quad w\in \mathbb{C}.$$ Remark. If we integrate this formally by parts, we obtain $$g(w)=\frac{1}{\pi}\iint_\mathbb{C}g(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}\left(\frac{1}{z-w}\right)\,dx\,dy.$$ Thus the "distribution derivative" of $1/(\pi(z-w))$ with respect to $z$ is the point mass $w$ ("Dirac delta-function"), in the sense that it is equal to $0$ away from $w$, and it is infinite at $w$ in such a way that its integral (total mass) is equal to $1$.

Hello! I'm just stuck with my complex analysis class. I was trying to make this problem through the pompeiu's formula but got stuck. The solution should be probably be the applying of this formula for a large disc, but i don't know how exactly. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Apply Stokes' theorem to the form

$$\omega(z) = -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{g(z)}{z-w}\,dz$$

and the region $\{ z : \varepsilon < \lvert z-w\rvert < R\}$ for large enough $R > 0$. Let $\varepsilon \searrow 0$.

Comment: Using Pompeiu's formula, I was able to show that $g(w) = - \frac{1}{\pi} \int \int_{D_R} \frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}} \frac{1}{z-w} dx dy$ for $w \in D_{R} = D(0,R)$, where $R > 0$ is large enough so that its boundary misses the support of $g$. I want to say, just let $R \to \infty$, and then we're down; but that doesn't seem rigorous enough. How do I justify taking this limit?

Comment: Once $R$ is large enough, such that $\operatorname{supp} g \subset D(0,R)$, the integral no longer depends on $R$, so taking the limit is straightforward.